# Server displays 404 when using https [nginx]

Tags: ssl, nginx, server

any help would be appreciated.

I have received an SSL cert from letsencrypt, and am trying to support both HTTP and HTTPS for my server. The cert is good, but I am getting 404's when trying to access my site using https. Here is my config file:

```
server {
  server_name my.domain.org;

  root /var/www/my.domain.org/htdocs;
  index index.php index.html index.html;

  server_name my.domain.org;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # # With php5-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/privkey.pem;

  server_name my.domain.org;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

  location / {
    root /var/www/my.domain.org/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config for https does not differ from http.

So, just copy same http configuration and add ssl specific parts:

```
# https
server {
  listen 443 ssl; 
  # for http2 support uncomment line bellow and comment line above
  # listen 443 ssl http2;  

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/privkey.pem;

  server_name my.domain.org;

  root /var/www/my.domain.org/htdocs;
  index index.php index.html index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}

#http
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/my.domain.org/htdocs;
  index index.php index.html index.html;

  server_name my.domain.org;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this. One more question for clarification, what you've pasted here would be my whole config file? (Omitting the other server {} block) Or would this merely replace the block I have for SSL right now?

Comment: @nginthrowaway I've updated my answer You can copy all